# LinqToDb MySql-запрос бросает MySqlException

Tags: c#, mysql, linq2db

До недавнего времени я, для работы с БД, использовал Dapper. Он мне всем нравится, но, по современным меркам, уж больно он "низкоуровневый".
Использовал EF Core, который работал стабильно, но слабоват, когда много однотипных таблиц вида `object_####_`, они часто меняются и меняется структура.
Требуются постоянные запросы с разным составом полей. И что понадобится в следующий раз пользователям, неизвестно.

Мне посоветовали LinqToDb, мол он всё это умеет. И да, он умел практически всё что надо.

Сделал я тестовое приложение. Идёт чтение, в n-тасков, большой таблицы из постгреса. После чтения записи, надо получить запись с сервера MySql, и обновить полученную запись в постгреса.

Таски запускаются через `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` ожидание через `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`.

Постгрес справляется на ура, всё хорошо. А, вот с MySql возникла проблема.

В таске выполняется так:

```
LinqToDbConnectionOptionsBuilder myBuilder = new LinqToDbConnectionOptionsBuilder();
myBuilder.UseMySql("тут ConnectionString");
await using DataConnection myDataConnection = new DataConnection(myBuilder.Build());

foreach (LayerTable item in page)
{
    DataParameter f = new DataParameter("@id", item.RowId, DataType.Int32);
    List<IDictionary<string, object>> result = myDataConnection.Query<IDictionary<string, object>>(Reader, $"select id from manual limit 10").ToList();
}
```

...

```
IDictionary<string, dynamic> Reader(IDataRecord reader)
{
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>(reader.FieldCount);
    object[] rowValues = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    int n = reader.GetValues(rowValues);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        values.Add(reader.GetName(j), rowValues[j]);
    }
    return values;
}
```

На строке `myDataConnection.Query` тупит секунд 10 и вываливается с `MySqlException` со словами

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.."

Запрос не выполняется ни разу, в `reader` не заходит. Причём, если этот же код выполнять в `main()`, то работает как часы. Ещё обратил внимание, что если остановиться на брейкпоинте, на строке запроса, то отладчик, в `DataConnection` объекта, в полях `DbConnection` показывает сообщение, что значение будет доступно, если все потоки будут выполняться.

Может есть какая-то особенность работы с MySql в LinqToDB?
С Постгресом нет проблем. Такой же код, но с Dapper работает на ура.

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас проблема со строкой соединения. Покажите её.

Comment: Linq2db - это, в первую очередь, ORM - **объектно**-реляционный маппер. А вы объекты не используете, колбасите сырые sql-запросы.

Comment: Тот же код, не в таске, а в мейн-методе, отрабатывает на ура. Выяснилось, что проблема в самоподнятом тунеле до сервера. Но, при этом, всё остальное - с постгресом, даппер, работают на ура, даже в таким тунелем.